# Symfony2: Add form in to another form

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-one

Is pretty simple:

I have a entity Agency with

```
/**
 * @var \Rewards\LocationBundle\Entity\Address
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\xxBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $address;
```

and I have a AgencyType for create Form:

```
   $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('address');
```

I have also AddressType

```
   $builder
        ->add('street')
        ->add('zipCode')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('country');
```

With this configuration if I put:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

in the twig template I only view the 'Select' form widget but I want to see all the fields from the form AgencyType AddressType.

How I can do that?

Comment: I think you are looking for "Embedded collections": http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: the relationship between Agency and Address entities is not a collection.

Comment: I added the class AddressType to question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the problem!

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('agents')
    ->add('address', new AddressType());
```

Clean and easy!

Comment: How to do this in symfony3
I'm facing some problem can anyone tell me how to Add form in to another form using symfony3
#php #symfony3

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 3/4 you should add a data class (Entity) of you entity in the AdressType form.
for instance:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Address::class,
    ]);
}
```